# Define predicate from following the rules Prolog

Tags: prolog

I'm new to Prolog and I would like to convert given rules to Prolog language.

I have to define a predicate **p(X1, Y1, X2, Y2)** ,where **X1**, **Y1** are integers, and **X2** and **Y2** are obtained from X1, Y1 following these rules:

1. if **Y1 ≤ 0** and **|X1|≤−Y1** then **X2** is **X1 + 1** and **Y2** is **Y1**
2. else if **X1 > 0** and **|Y1| < X1** then **X2** is **X1**, and **Y2** is **Y1+1**
3. else if **Y1 > 0** and **−Y1 < X1 ≤ Y1** then **X2** is **X1−1**, and **Y2** is **Y1**
4. else **X2** is **X1** and **Y2** is **Y1−1**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll provide a steer, here is rule 1:

```
p(X1, Y1, X2, Y2) :-
    Y1 =< 0,
    abs(X1) =< -Y1,
    % Cut, to prevent processing alternatives
    !,
    X2 is X1 + 1,
    Y2 is Y1.
```

Sample output in swi-prolog:

```
?- p(-3, -5, X2, Y2).
X2 = -2,
Y2 = -5.
```